# How to use template function as comparator in STL algorithm ex: make_heap

Tags: c++, templates, stl

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
bool HeapComparator (T,T);

template <typename T>
void PrintArray(T arr,int size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
int arr[7]={1,4,2,5,7,6,3};
int size=7;
PrintArray(arr,size);

cout<<"Max Heap:"<<endl;
make_heap(arr,arr+size); //creates MAX Heap, as no comparator provided.
PrintArray(arr,size);

cout<<"Min Heap:"<<endl;
make_heap(arr,arr+size,HeapComparator); //compilation error here.
PrintArray(arr,size);

return 0;
}   

template <typename T>
bool HeapComparator(T a, T b)
{
if(a>b)
    return false;
else
    return true;
}
```

It doesn't work. How to use template function as comparator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate your template function:

```
make_heap(arr,arr+size,HeapComparator<int>);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the template argument when you instantiate the template. Also consider making the arguments of the comparator const refs:

NOTE: I have also included several other improvements to your code - for instance I have simplified the HashComparator.

NOTE2: in this particular case you could have used `std::greater<int>` as comparator instead of your custom comparator.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
bool HeapComparator (const T&,const T&);

template <typename T>
void PrintArray(T arr,int size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
      cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
  int arr[7]={1,4,2,5,7,6,3};
  int size=7;
  PrintArray(arr,size);

  cout<<"Max Heap:"<<endl;
  make_heap(arr,arr+size); //creates MAX Heap, as no comparator provided.
  PrintArray(arr,size);

  cout<<"Min Heap:"<<endl;
  make_heap(arr,arr+size,HeapComparator<int>); 
  PrintArray(arr,size);

  return 0;
}   

template <typename T>
bool HeapComparator(const T& a,const T& b) {
  return a>b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to encapsulate it in a class.

```
struct HeapComparator {
    template <typename T>
    bool operator () (T,T);
};

make_heap(arr,arr+size,HeapComparator()); 

template <typename T>
bool HeapComparator::operator () (T a, T b)
{
if(a>b)
    return false;
else
    return true;
}
```

C++14 generic lambdas will generate the boilerplate automatically:

```
make_heap(arr,arr+size,[]( auto a, auto b ) { return …; } );
```

Note that your comparator computes `!(a>b)` or `a <= b` which is not a valid strict weak ordering. Turning it into a valid condition would yield `a<b` which is the default.

Comment: +1 for showing bugs in my code, and reminding me about strict weak ordering.